# Wireless active connection not shown in NM drop-down menu

Tags: 12.04, network-manager

Since yesterday I edited my Wifi connection at home (adding a WPA Key) and updated my connection in NM.

The connection works and I can surf the web.

But the NM menu doesn't show any connection, just:

*v Enable Networking

v Enable Wireless

Connection Information

Edit Connections...*

Thanks for any help!

Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

image here: http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/download/file.php?id=4178&mode=view

Comment: I have noticed that if I switch off and then on my laptop wifi device then the menu is correctly shown. But why not at the start? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved thanks to #5 here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1027638/comments/5

I edit:

sleep 1